# Angular2: how to know if the browser reloads or not?

Tags: events, angular

This is a paragraph from ng-book2: Javascript, by default, propagates the click event to all the parent components. Because the click event is propagated to parents, our browser is trying to follow the empty link.
To fix that, we need to make the click event handler to return false. This will ensure the browser won’t try to refresh the page.

Question: how to know if the browser reloads or not? I can not detect it by eyes.

Here is part of my code:

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'reddit-article',
    inputs: ['article'],
    templateUrl: 'app/redditArticle.html'
})

export class RedditArticleComponent {

    article: Article;

    constructor() {
       console.log('Just loaded!');
    }

    voteUp() {
        this.article.voteUp();
    }

    voteDown() {
        this.article.voteDown();
    }
}

export class Article {
    //title: string;
    //link: string;
    //votes: number;

    constructor(public title: string, public link: string, public votes: number) {
        //this.title = title;
        //this.link = link;
        //this.votes = votes;
    }
    voteUp(): boolean {
        this.votes++;
        return false;
    }

    voteDown(): boolean {
        this.votes--;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log('just loaded');
  }
}
```

When you open the browser dev tools you know a reload happened when an additional `just loaded` is printed. Ensure `[x] preserve log` is checked in the console (Chrome).

Comment: In the book, it says without "return false;" in functions of voteUp() and voteDown(), it will reload the page. When I tried your suggestion to print information to console, and find out there is no difference with "return false" or without "return false". Do you why?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the doc?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is my code: https://github.com/junjunruan/Angular2-reloadPage

Comment: is there any way to fire event before page is refreshed in Angular 2 ?

Comment: What do you mean with refresh? What event? For what purpose?